# Does PROC PHREG (SAS) drop observations if there isn't a match when using strata?

Tags: sas

I am trying to run a model using PROC PHREG. In the data I notice that there are some instances where I don't have both counterparts of the matching variable (the case is missing, control only). Will these individuals be excluded, or will the model run with them?

Answer (score 0):

Any observations with missing values that are being used in the PROC will be excluded. They will not be excluded pairwise though - meaning if your control is present but the case data is not, that record alone will be excluded. You need to ensure that you have a match for each one.

Comment: You have to spend the time deleting unmatched ones. Whether you program that or do it manually is your choice - or a new question, but it won't be excluded by default.